# Stuck in an Infinite Loop with Multiple If Conditions inside a loop

Tags: javascript

Can you please let me know why this code is generating an infinite loop? I have tried to limit the steps between `> min ) && (i <=` logic but it's still sticking in the loop.

```js
var min = -9.00;
var max = 14.00;
for (var i = min; i < max;) {
  console.log(i);
  if((i > min ) && (i <= -2.00)) {i += (0.25);}
  if((i > -2.00 ) && (i <= 0.00)){i += (0.5);}
  if((i > 0.00 ) && (i <= 6.00)) {i += (0.25);}
  if((i > 6.00 ) && (i <= max))  {i += (0.5);}
  }
```

Comment: Have you gone through the code using a debugger?

Comment: You initialize `i` with `min` so you never satisfied any `if` condition, so `i` never change -> infinite loop: `i > min` is false because at the beginning `i == min`, maybe you want `OR` condition and not `AND`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have an infinite loop. Because `i = -9.00` and your first if is `i > min` which `min = -9.00` its the same not greather. just change `>` to `>=`

```js
var min = -9.00;
var max = 14.00;
for (var i = min; i < max;) {
  console.log(i);
  if((i >= min ) && (i <= -2.00)) {i += (0.25);}
  if((i > -2.00 ) && (i <= 0.00)){i += (0.5);}
  if((i > 0.00 ) && (i <= 6.00)) {i += (0.25);}
  if((i > 6.00 ) && (i <= max))  {i += (0.5);}
}
```